# Загрузка файлов с другого сервера на свой сервер php

Tags: php

Есть ссылка переходя по которому начинается загрузка файла - http://zakupki.gov.ru/223/purchase/public/download/download.html?id=3324768 . Вопрос такой как загрузит файл на свой сервер переходя по этой ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего через `cURL`:

```
$fp = fopen('uploads/download.pdf', 'wb'); // Открываем файл
$ch = curl_init("http://zakupki.gov.ru/223/purchase/public/download/download.html?id=3324768");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // Передаём дескриптор файла, туда сбросится результат
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Тогда уж `file_put_contents('file.pdf', file_get_contents($path));`.